# Dead Kernel i python when I when I run a certain code

Tags: python, kernel

when I run a certain code in both Spyder and Jupyter, I get "Dead Kernel" if I try to run it several times.

Is there anyone who cares to look through my code and provide possible solutions
What my code would like to do is ask for the path to a folder.
Then take the .csv files that are in the folder, skip the files that are not .csv, Import the files one at a time as a data frame. For the columns that are objects (txt), remove the text before the last "" and all "" and " ", after which rename the columns. If a particular column has a particular cell value then it must make it another value.
Then the data frame must be exported as an excel file and not csv.
Then the code must take the next csv file in the folder.

I hope it is clear what I have written, otherwise ask me

Regards

```
import os
import pandas as pd

pcid=os.getlogin()

print('--')
print('-- hello '+ pcid)
print("--")

def remove_leading_whitespace(cell):
    return cell.lstrip()

data_in = input("the path for folder?: ")
print("--")

folder_path = data_in
folder_path = folder_path.replace('"','')

files = os.listdir(folder_path)

for file_name in files:
    file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, file_name)
    
    if os.path.isfile(file_path) and file_name.lower().endswith('.csv'):
        # Perform operations on the file
        print("Processing file:", file_name)
        
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path, delimiter=";", decimal=",")
        try:
            for col in df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns:
                df[col] = [" "*0*s.count("\\")+s.split("\\")[-1] for s in df[col]]
                df[col] = df[col].apply(remove_leading_whitespace)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error processing file:", file_name, "Error:", e)
            continue

        df.columns.values[0] = "Product"
        df.columns.values[1] = "Market"
        df.columns.values[2] = "Period"
        df.columns.values[3] = "Measure"
        df.columns.values[4] = "Data"
        
        df['Measure'] = df['Measure'].str.replace('Loyalty Value Seg', 'Loyalty Value')
        
        file_path = file_path.replace(".csv", ".xlsx")
        df.to_excel(file_path, index=False)
    else:
        print(f"Skipping file: {file_name} as it is not a CSV file.")

print('--')
print("Done")
print('\a')
```

Regards

Comment: And what happens if you run your script "normally" from the shell?

Comment: When I run my script it works and all is fine, then I run it again and then I get "Dead kernel"

Comment: You can't get 'Dead kernel' when running it from the shell. What do you mean by "when I run it it works and when I run it again it doesn't'?? You need to be much more specific.

Comment: Then I do not understand, when I try to run 2 times in jupyter or spyder then i get "dead kernel". As a beginner, I mainly use spyder, still after 1½ years since I started

Comment: Is it only with your full-size, real data? For example, if you take only a few rows of your data and run it on that, does it work much more before failing or fails the same? If you never get 'dead kernel' with other simple Pandas use and it works with a small amount of data then you are hitting a memory issue. But you don't tell us much about the actual data or system you are using.

Comment: my data is 8 csv files and the total for all is 758 kb, so noting big

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution to my problem, by using time.sleep I no longer have the error.

```
    df.to_excel(file_path, index=False)
    time.sleep(15) # new line, so it is waiting for to_excel to finis
```